# Switch from ListView to sub ListView in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have an app where the `MainActivity` which creates an `ActionBar` with `tabs` (used `ActionBarSherlock` for this).

Each `tab` loads a `Fragment`. One fragment has a `ListView` in which I load items. Each item responds to an `OnItemClick` event.

When an item is clicked then the app gets data from a webserver. I want to show that data in a new `ListView`. But that's where i'm stuck.

How can I switch from my first main `ListView` to a 'sub-ListView`?

Keep in mind that my current View is a fragment and that it's loaded inside a tab. I want to remain on the same tab when I show the new 'sub' `ListView`.

Also, when I push the back `button` on the Android device, then I want it to show the main `ListView` again.

So actually, kinda like the iPhone does it with their `TableView`.

Comment: If you use Fragments, you can replace your current Fragment to the one you want. Don't forget to add them to the stack (.addToBackStack(..)) to maintain the correct working flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have te use another `Fragment` in order to do that. You need to create that `Fragment` and then replace the old one with the `FragmentTransaction` and if you want to use the "back" button  you need to add the new fragment to the `Backstack`.
If these `ListFragment` are quite different in terms of data, I'd have 2 fragment classes (e.g. : FirstListFragment, SecondListFragment).

Here's some code from an App I worked on :

```
    // Here I get the FragmentTransaction

    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    // I replace it with a new Fragment giving it data. Here you need to tell 
    // the FragmentTransaction what (or actually where) and by what you want to replace. 

    ft.replace(R.id.fraglist, new ModuleFragment(lpId, sqId, sqName));
```

The R.id.fraglist should be defined in your XML layout (except if you programmatically created your layout). It's simply the ID of your default fragment.

```
    // I set the animation

    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);

    // I add it to the backstack so I can use the back button

    ft.addToBackStack(null);

    // Then I finally commit so it happens !

    ft.commit();
```

You can also use a Bundle to parse data like so :

```
    Bundle moduleBundle = new Bundle();
    moduleBundle.putString("id", id);
    moduleBundle.putString("description", description);
    moduleFragment.setArguments(moduleBundle);
```